# Why does Aptana Studio 3 give "missing DOCTYPE" error for lowercase doctype?

Tags: html, doctype, case-sensitive, aptana3

According to the HTML5 specification, the [doctype preamble is case insensitive](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-author-view/syntax.html#the-doctype). So why does Aptana Studio 3 complain about a lowercase doctype for HTML documents?

Comment: Example..[.](http://w3c.org)?

Comment: @Jared: Basically, if you have `<!doctype html>` instead of `<!DOCTYPE html>`, it will give the missing DOCTYPE error. I'm guessing the validator used is based on old specifications that tried to conform to XML.

Comment: @Jared: `<!doctype html><html><head><title></title></head><body></body></html>` --should I give you instructions on how to start up Aptana Studio 3, now?

Comment: @Jared: If you want to enable HTML validation in .php files, you need to edit your HTML content-type and add `*.php` (or `*.phtml` as I prefer). But that's a completely separate issue.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - I leave it to you. `:)`

Comment: @Jared: I apologize if I came off a bit dickish. I've been up for too long. =P

Comment: @Lèsemajesté - We've all had our moments, me maybe more than median. I'd personally forget about the described error, but you know how that goes.

Answer (score 1):

Presumably because in XML, `<!doctype html>` is not valid; XML requires the keyword `DOCTYPE` in uppercase. So if you want to process your HTML5 document using generic XML tools, you need `<!DOCTYPE html>`.